# Create SSL Certificate on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssl, openssl, google-compute-engine

I' following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates) by Google to put SSL certificate on Google Compute Engine, but after I run the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048
openssl req -new -key example.key -out example.csr
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create certificate --certificate example.csr --private-key example.key
```

, I found the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Some requests did not succeed:
>
> - The SSL certificate could not be parsed.

However, if you search for it in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22The+SSL+certificate+could+not+be+parsed.%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) you find that they are practically useless. I even don't know what is missing here, as I followed the tutorial just as it is written.

So why did I get such error and how can I proceed to create the SSL certificate?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're specifying the ***.crt** file as the certificate and not the *.csr

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create certificate --certificate example.crt --private-key example.key
```

If you're generating a self-signed cert, you would need to generate it using the key and the csr:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in example.csr -signkey example.key -out example.crt
```

Finally, you can also add *--verbosity debug* flag to your gcloud commands for more info on what's going on.